# using html tag for widget area title

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I want to register a sidebar with my html custom title on Widgets area.

My register widget function like ;

```
register_sidebar(array(
  'name' => __( '<img src="'.$keepAdminImages.'/_assets/_img/keepSignature.png" />' ),
  'id' => 'keepSense-Left',
  'description' => __( 'keepSense Temanızda Sol alanda yer alacak bileşenlerinizi bu kısma sürükleyip bırakabilirsiniz.' ),
  'before_title' => '<h1>',
  'after_title' => '</h1>'
));
$keepAdminImages = get_bloginfo('template_url');
```

Its output seems like : http://prntscr.com/tbbmw How can use some html tag in that area ? Any help ? Thanks.

Comment: Check out http://wpmu.org/wordpress-widget-title-html/

Comment: @Rikesh i mean i want tou use some html codes on admin area please see the screenshot. [SCREENSHOT Here.](http://prntscr.com/tbbmw)

Answer (score 0):

Fatih, i think you can not use images on admin area. Did you check http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/widgets.php#L0 ?

Comment: i just check it but i guess should be a way